# How to Ctrl+Shift+Down using Google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write an Google App Script for a google sheet that I have. The number of values I have in column D will change every week, and I am trying to copy those values to paste into another sheet.

[image]

So far, I can't find any code that will do the equivalent of selecting D2, and doing a Ctrl + Shift + down + copy.

```
function ELATerminationTransfer() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('D2').activate();SpreadsheetApp.getSelection().getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate};
```

Anyone know of a simple fix?

Comment: In this example sheet.getLastRow()-1 is the number of rows in column D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function testSelection()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Destination');

  // copy column values to destination sheet
  sourceSheet
    .getRange('D2:D')
    .copyTo(destSheet.getRange('D2'), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select by this way

```
function myFunction(){
  var cel = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()
  var end = cel.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(cel.getA1Notation()+':'+end.getA1Notation()).activate()
}
```